# Locate a cell using 2 values in a VBA form

Tags: excel, vba

My input form contains 2 texts which corresponds to a specific row & column header of my worksheet. I want to use the 2 selected texts in the form to locate the cell, and edit the respective cell's value.

1 of the value is part of an array in a Listbox (e.g. located in ListBox2.Column(0,1))

The other value is from a combo box (e.g. cmbName).

How can I use these 2 values to locate the cell? I thought maybe index/match will work, but it seems all too complicated.. any help will be appreciated - thanks!

I tried doing a double for loop to locate the column, but I can't figured out how to locate the right row.

```
For m=27 To finalcol

    For n = 0 to ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Column(0,n) = Trim(ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(1,m).Text) Then
    MsgBox ("Matched!")
    End If 
    Next n
Next m
```

I get the "Matched!" output, but I'm not sure how to achieve the next step. Is this approach fundamentally limited?

Comment: So you are trying to match a column of a listbox with row 1 of a worksheet? Why not use MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

First you can find the row corresponding to cmbName, and then the column as you already did:

```
    ' Find the row corresponding to cmbName
    For r=2 To ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Masterlist").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If cmbName = Trim(ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(r,1).Text)
           therow=r
        End if
    Next r

    ' Find the column corresponding to ListBox2 column 0:
For m=27 To finalcol
        For n = 0 to ListBox2.ListCount - 1
            If ListBox2.Column(0,n) = Trim(ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(1,m).Text) Then
                If ListBox2.Selected(n)
                    ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(therow,m).Text = ListBox2.Column(1,n)
                End If 
            End If 
        Next n
    Next m
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest solution for me. Love it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the double for loop it would be something like:

```
Public Sub Test 

'Loops through all items in Listbox2'
For n = 0 to ListBox2.ListCount - 1
  FindCell ListBox2.List(n)
Next

End Sub

Private Sub FindCell (lstValue As String)

'Sets the ws As a variable we can use'
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Masterlist")

Dim ColumnLetter as String

'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Loops through each cell in Row 1'
For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & lCol)
  If cell.Value = lstValue Then 'Checks if the cell value is equal to the item we passed in from the ListBox'
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, cell.Column).Address, "$")(1) 'To use Worksheet.Range below, we need to find the column letter'
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row 'Goes from the bottom of the file up to the first cell that contains a value and stores the row # as a variable'
    For Each cellCol in ws.Range(ColumnLetter & "2:" ColumnLetter & lRow) 'Now we need to check each cell in the row for the value in the combo box'
      If cellCol.Value = cmbName.Value Then
        Messagebox ("Matched")
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Let me know how this goes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

I dummied up a worksheet that looks like this ...

[image]

... I then added a named range to that matrix called **rngDataSet**.

Then, using this code, it demonstrates logic that will ultimately find and select the relevant cell based on the row and column headings you provide.  You should be able to adapt this code to your own logic.

```
Public Sub FindCell(ByVal rngDataSet As Range, ByVal strRowHeader As String, ByVal strColHeader As String, ByVal varNewValue As Variant)
    Dim objCell As Range, objColCell As Range, objRowCell As Range

    ' Find the column header
    For Each objCell In rngDataSet.Rows(1).Cells
        If UCase(Trim(objCell.Text)) = UCase(Trim(strColHeader)) Then
            Set objColCell = objCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Find the row header
    For Each objCell In rngDataSet.Columns(1).Cells
        If UCase(Trim(objCell.Text)) = UCase(Trim(strRowHeader)) Then
            Set objRowCell = objCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If objColCell Is Nothing Or objRowCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Either 1 or both of the supplied headers were not found.", vbCritical, "Error"
    Else
        rngDataSet.Worksheet.Cells(objRowCell.Row, objColCell.Column) = varNewValue
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub DoFindCell()
    Dim strRowHeader As String, strColHeader As String

    strRowHeader = InputBox("Row Header ...", "Row Header", "Row Header ")
    strColHeader = InputBox("Column Header ...", "Column Header", "Col Header ")

    FindCell Sheet1.Range("rngDataSet"), strRowHeader, strColHeader, “New Value”
End Sub
```

I hope that helps.

**"DoFindCell" only exists to invoke the logic, that should be replaced by your own list/combo box values.**